# Coursera Scala week 3 filter method not working

Tags: scala

I am doing coursera scala course, working on week 3 assignment. I have completed half of the functions. Stuck with filter method. I do not want an answer, what I want is understanding or hint of what I am missing.

Here is the requirement:

/**
    * This method takes a predicate and returns a subset of all the elements
    * in the original set for which the predicate is true.
    */

```
def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = ???
```

Here is my code:

```
override def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet =  filterAcc(p, new Empty)

 def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
  if(this.isEmpty)
    acc
  else if (p ( elem)) {
    left.filterAcc(p, acc incl elem)
    right.filterAcc(p, acc incl elem)
  }
  else
  {
    left.filterAcc(p, acc )
    right.filterAcc(p, acc )
  }
```

**Update**:  Adding some more context to this problem. Here is the base class:

```
abstract class TweetSet {

def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = ???

def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet

def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = ???

def isEmpty: Boolean = ???

def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean

}
```

I have two implementations Empty and NonEmpty representing sets with and without any elements.

Test Case:

```
val set1 = new Empty
val set2 = set1.incl(new Tweet("a", "a body", 20))
val set3 = set2.incl(new Tweet("b", "b body", 20))
val c = new Tweet("c", "c body", 7)
val d = new Tweet("d", "d body", 9)
val set4c = set3.incl(c)
val set4d = set3.incl(d)
val set5 = set4c.incl(d)  

test("filter: a on set5") {
 new TestSets {
 assert(size(set5.filter(tw => tw.user == "a")) === 1) // this fails
 }
}
```

Result:

[info] - filter: a on set5 *** FAILED ***
[info]   0 did not equal 1 (TweetSetSuite.scala:64)

Comment: From that code snippet alone, it is hard to understand your data structure. What is `this`, what are `left` and `right`, etc. Do you understand how filter on lists work? Where exactly are you stuck? Do you have some failing test cases?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do know how filter should work, my problem is with the accumulator not working as expected. Basically, the accumulator doesn't hold correct values when it is executed. Adding the test case to the main question.

Comment: I chose to let `filter()` remain abstract in the `TweetSet` definition and put the implementations in the subclasses. The `Empty` implementation is trivial. The `NonEmpty` implementation is a single if/else statement.

Comment: I am also following the same logic. But my logic screws up with binary tree. basically I have to process current element, then look to left and right nodes at each step. my current code represents that understanding, but all in all, I do feel something is wrong with my else and else if condition.

Comment: Tried this logic, this also failed:      ` if(this.isEmpty)
      acc
    else
    {
      left.filterAcc(p, if(p(elem)) acc incl elem else acc)
      right.filterAcc(p, if(p(elem)) acc incl elem else acc)
    }`

Comment: You don't need `filterAcc()` if the implementations are in the subclasses.

Comment: I still don't really understand the left and right thing, but it seems you are only returning the result from the call on `right` (because it is the last expression in that code block). The `left.filterAcc` call is apparently lost. So that looks fishy.

Comment: Okay, will check about direct call to filter. Also if I use left.filterAcc union right.filterAcc, that should preserve both the evaluations, right?

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, my Empty set implementation was having issue. Now it works. Thanks @stholzm

Comment: Thanks @jwvh. I will work on direct call implementation also.

Answer (score 2):

```
 def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    val set = if(p(elem)) acc.incl(elem) else acc
    right.filterAcc(p, left.filterAcc(p, set))
  }
```

basically you need to remember that you have to filter 3 'sets': elem, left, and right, and then combine them (join)